# Google Sheet formula is giving an error and does not convert the dates to right format

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using below mentioned formula which repeats the `Name of Employee` multiple times if he takes leaves on multiple dates, if he takes 3 leaves then its name will be repeated thrice with the dates as you can see in attached picture.

the problem i have been facing is it gives an error `#VALUE!` and the dates does not come in the right format that is `MM-DD-YYYY`.

Your help will be appreciated.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(Data!F3:F, ","))="",,
 Data!B3:B&"×"&SPLIT(Data!F3:F, ","))), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"))))
```

**Picture 1 Data:**

[image]

**Picture 2 Result:**

[image]

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sbs43YmYblVnOb3CPNqT06oKD8YizY9ekoPIeuRGtgA/edit#gid=951885978)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the `#VALUE!`, try this:

```
=arrayformula(query(iferror(split(flatten(iferror(Data!B3:B&char(9999)&split(Data!F3:F,","),)),char(9999)),),"where Col2 is not null",0))
```

Also, `char(9999)` is used instead of `"x"` because if an employee name contains an `x`, their record will not show up.

Also, you can just highlight Col C and format the date however you like, using the Format > menu.

[image]

To switch the colums:

```
=arrayformula({"Absent/Full Leave","Names";query(iferror(split(flatten(iferror(Data!B3:B&char(9999)&split(Data!F3:F,","),)),char(9999)),),"select Col2, Col1 where Col2 is not null",0)})
```

NOTE: The formula is in cell `B1` and includes the header names.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much @Aresvik for sorting it out. Is it possible to come the date first and name after ?

Comment: Solution updated. Make sure there is nothing in cells `B2:B` or `C1:C`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Text() function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) and embed it within your formula.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(text(IFERROR(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(Data!F3:F, ","))="",, Data!B3:B&"×"&SPLIT(Data!F3:F, ","))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null"))),"MM-DD-YYYY"))`

[See example result here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4dOec1dfVRUH26alB1YJGkF2PQI5-YlDov3Ga6rC0k/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you but if you see still the error `#VALUE!` is appearing ?